# Problem creating RichFaces page theme

Tags: jsf, maven, themes, richfaces

I'm trying to create a RichFaces page theme using the [instructions here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingAThemeForrichpageComponent).  I know NOTHING about Maven, so I've followed the instructions as best I can, but I've run into an error and don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I followed the instructions on [the page](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CreatingAThemeForrichpageComponent), and then run this command:

```
mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.richfaces.cdk -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-theme -DarchetypeVersion=3.3.3.Final -DartifactId=test -DgroupId=org.richfaces.docs -Dversion=1.0mvn archetype:create -DarchetypeGroupId=org.richfaces.cdk -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-theme -DarchetypeVersion=3.3.3
```

However, when I run the command I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.0:create (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Error creating from archetype: org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DownloadException: Error downloading org.richfaces.cdk:maven-archetype-theme:jar:3.3.3. Could not transfer artifact org.richfaces.cdk:maven-archetype-theme:jar:3.3.3 from/to repository.jboss.com (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/): Access denied to: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/org/richfaces/cdk/maven-archetype-theme/3.3.3/maven-archetype-theme-3.3.3.jar
[ERROR] org.richfaces.cdk:maven-archetype-theme:jar:3.3.3
```

I tried browsing to http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/, but I get an "Access Denied" error, just as stated in the error message.  My question is, how do I rectify this?  Is there a different URL that I should be using?  If so, do I edit the Maven settings.xml file and use the new URL?  I'd REALLY appreciate anyone that can give me some direction on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link of the `Jboss Repository for Maven` specified in the `jboss_profile.txt` seems to be outdated.

You can try to replace all `<url>` of all `Jboss Repository for Maven`  with https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/ in your `Maven settings.xml`